# list index out of range.split on input?

Tags: python-3.x, text-based

i'm running into "out of range" while hitting enter and imputing single words. I understand why they are out of range, i just can't find how to fix the issue. this is my code:

```
commands = {
'help': help,
'exit': exit,
'look': look,
'stats': thePlayer.printStats,
's':thePlayer.move_South}

def runCmd(cmd, args, player):
    commands[cmd](args, player)

def help(args):
    print(commands)

def play():
    main1()
    World.loadTiles()
    #These lines load the starting room and display the text
    room = World.tileExists(player.locationX, player.locationY)
    print(room.introText())
    while player.isAlive():
        room = World.tileExists(player.locationX, player.locationY)
        room.modifyPlayer(player)
        # Check again since the room could have changed the player's state
        if player.isAlive():
            print("\nHp:%d\%d  Mp:%d\%d\n"%(player.hp,player.maxHp,player.mp,player.maxMp))
            print(room.printEnemy())
            availableActions = room.availableActions()            
            for action in availableActions:
                print(action)
            actionInput = input('Action: ')
            action = actionInput.lower()
            action = action.split()            
            print(action)
        if action[0] in commands:
            runCmd(action[0],action[1], player)
```

i realize i'm not passing an "action[1]" and that just hitting enter isn't in "commands" causing my error. i'm new to coding so creating a game is how i'm teaching myself.

i'm trying to get to where i can type:   enter, single word (help, stats), double words (look rat), other things with more words ( buy big sword) and so on. any help on how i can code this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

How about testing

```
len(action)
```

before calling runCmd? Thus, you can know if there are one word, two words, or more than two words.
If there is only one word, you can call:

```
runCmd(action[0], None, player)
```

If there are two words, you can call your current function. If there are more  than two words, it's a bit tricky. You can pass the whole action variable. Then, the called function has to know how many parameters it needs.

Comment: that would be a very brute force method to make it work. but, that would be adding 20 some times of extra code that i'm sure can be simplified. i know there is a   *args  i could pass, instead which (to my knowledge) will pass as my arguments as i want, however i don't know how exactly to use it yet.

Comment: I have never used the splat operator, so I can't help you. Perhaps you can find some clues [here](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/04/args-and-kwargs-in-python-explained/). It's Python 2, but I think it works in Python 3, too.